# how to install ans use cppclean on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, compilation

I want to compile a source code, below error occurred.

`cppcleant not found`

I searched and found that cppclean must installed with

`$ pip install --upgrade cppclean`
the result is

`successfully installed cppclean-0.13`
but compile error is steal remained and when I type **cppclean** result is
** command cppclean not found **
what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, cppclean will not install  and we must identify CPPCLEAN path to cmake with flag.
It worked for me.